# Problema ao utilizar consulta

Tags: mysql, laravel, conexão

Estou tendo o seguinte problema ao utilizar alguma consulta no meu Laravel. Estranhei esse IP 192.168.1.1, no meu arquivo .env coloquei 192.168.1.31 onde está localizado meu banco de dados.

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo? Segue abaixo erro e códigos.

> [2019-07-12 14:08:03] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access
>   denied for user '[meu usuario]'@'192.168.1.1' (using password: YES)
>   {"exception":"[object] (PDOException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[HY000]
>   [1045] Access denied for user 'sul'@'192.168.1.1' (using password:
>   YES) at
>   /var/www/html/apilivezilla/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68)
>       [stacktrace]

Arquivo .env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:hTtALqjgM1jBb5iNKxebWlem2l+mrPr67ywq4Ab38mw=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://[MEU IP]

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=[meu db]
DB_USERNAME=[meu usuario]
DB_PASSWORD=[minha senha]
DB_HOST=192.168.1.31


BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Arquivo database.php (Não acho que esteja influenciando)

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Database Connection Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
| to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
| you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
|
*/

'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Database Connections
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
| Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
| supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
|
|
| All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
| so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
| choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
|
*/

'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '192.168.1.31'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', '[meu db]'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', '[meu usuario]'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '[minha senha]'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ],

    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Migration Repository Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
| your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
| the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
|
*/

'migrations' => 'migrations',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Redis Databases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
| provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
| such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
|
*/

'redis' => [

    'client' => 'predis',

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],

],
```

];

Comment: O banco é local ou em rede? Se for local, provavelmente o certo não é 127.0.0.1? Ou localhost?

Comment: O banco é em rede. Em outras duas apis que tenho aqui os bancos são locais e funcionam normalmente.  Já esse é outro servidor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A coisa mais importante a observar na mensagem de erro:

```
Access denied for user '[meu usuario]'@'192.168.1.1' (using password: YES)
```

Esse erro indica que o usuário em questão não tem permissão para acessar o banco de dados, isso pode ocorrer por alguns motivos:

1. Há um erro em seu arquivo .env e você deve informar o nome do banco de dados, do usuário e senha corretos nas variáveis `DB_DATABASE`, `DB_USERNAME`, `DB_PASSWORD`, respectivamente.
2. O usuário que está tentando acessar não tem permissão para acessar o banco de dados de maneira remota, usando o ip 192.168.1.31 para conexão seu usuário utiliza a rede para se conectar de maneira externa.
3. A configuração do banco de dados MySQL não recebe conexões remotas.

### Criar usuário para conexão remota

```sql
CREATE USER 'novousuario'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'senha';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'seubanco'.* TO 'novousuario'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

### Aceitar conexões remotas no MySQL (em um Ubuntu 18.04)

Edite o arquivo **mysqld.cnf**

```
sudo vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

Altere o **bind-address** de:

```
#bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

Para:

```
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

Reinicie o MySQL

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

Comment: Observe que o item 2, ao criar o usuário no MySQL dizemos se a conexão dele é apenas local ou de uma origem especifica ou qualquer origem, por padrão o usuário `root` se conecta apenas localmente.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, vou analisar.

Comment: Estranhei no erro que ele mostrou 192.168.1.1 sendo que coloquei no arquivo 192.168.1.31. Achei que ele poderia não estar conseguindo pegar a configuração.

Comment: Não ignore isso, talvez o arquivo .env não está carregando, saber mais de sua stack é importante, mas se está usando o servidor embutido que sobe com o `artisan`, reinicie ele toda vez que mudar uma variável de ambiente